# Strange things in C/C++ code (ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'xxx' with no type)

Tags: c++, c, extern

I am a C/C++ newbie, so this might be a dumb question,
I have the following problem, I have a method in a c++ lib which is exported using 
extern 'C' and it is being called by another method from a different c file. 
So, I needed some structures in the c++ code, so the "smart" thing to do seemed to be simply add the structures to the .h file of the first class and import it. When I did so, the strangest thing happened. The C code which worked fine, broke saying three stupid things (note that the structures were simply moved from the code to the header). So, I have 3 instances, read errors, saying:

1. Expected ; before * token;
2. Iso C++ forbids declaration of 'someclassname' with no type
3. type 'someclassname' could not be resolved

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us the code, the offending error message, and the compiler command.

Comment: hmmm... this sounds like a case of "post your code"

Comment: It seems like the class you're trying to use isn't included in the file (or header) file. You'll need to either include the correct file or state a forward declaration (like, class UnresolvedClassName;). But, show us the code.

Comment: If it is `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ...`, then why `c` tag?

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is **difficult**. I suggest you stick to one language per source file.

Comment: The code needs to be posted, in case a sensible answer has to be written to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler thinks that "someclassname" is a variable name. You wrote something like

```
Employee* newguy = foo();
```

And the compiler thinks you gave the name of an undeclared variable, Employee, complained about that, complained that a * doesn't go after a variable name, and so on.

Go look at where you think you're explaining what "someclassname" is, because the compiler isn't getting it.

ps: post your code!